# Why is my return false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just a simple question I can't seem to figure out... I have a simple `a href=` link on my page and I want it to link to the other page with an anchor. But the `return false;` doesn't work? Can't see why this won't work. Because I've done this a couple of times before.

*Little clarification:*

What I expect the `return false` to do is not show the #anchor behind the URL. Just show the `/dir/` link.

Heres my code:

```
<a class="backto" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;">Back</a>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("a.backto").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = "/dir/#anchor";
        return false;
});
```

Like I said. Simple code. But it doesn't work. I tried using `a href="#"` before I put in the `href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;"`. But that didn't work either... can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_". What you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: perhaps `$("a.backto")` is executing before the page has loaded the html with that anchor in it

Comment: You're trying to mix behavior in HTML and JS. Leave jQuery listener and change HTML to `<a class="backto" href="#">Back</a>`

Comment: add `console.log($("a.backto").length)` just before the code you've shown ... is it 0?

Comment: What's the point of your JS code? If you're making a redirect anyway why not just use the `href` attribute of the `a` element?

Comment: What I expect the `return false` to do is not show the #anchor behind the URL. Just show the `/dir/` link.

Comment: @Jay-oh that's not what `return false` does. The URL fragment will always be shown

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan eh? Then I've been lied to my whole life :) No really... I'm kind of new to this whole jQuery. Is there away to strip the `#anchor` from the url when clicked?

Comment: Nope. It needs to be sent - assuming you're sending it the next page which needs to read it from the URL.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and what if I used some code that when this `back` link is clicked it would go to `/dir/#anchor` and scroll down some how? Is that possible? Something like `on('click', function(e){goto: /dir/ scrolldown:200px;});`

Comment: Yes - although it's not straightforward. You would need to implement [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and [popState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok. Ill have a look into that then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below HTML and jQuery. It will show only '/dir/' behind the URL:

```
<a class="backto" href="#">Back</a>
$("a.backto").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = window.location + '/dir/';
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But this doesn't scroll to the anchor... too bad...